# Start minikube with Docker driver in rootless not working because of fuse-overlay unit

Tags: linux, docker, minikube

I have an issue using Minikube with rootless docker.

I recently upgraded my Debian 10 to a Debian 11 with a `5.10.0-16-amd64` kernel version.

Then I have set up a rootless Docker, and its currently working well.

I have followed the documentation of Kubernetes about [rootless docker](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/).

But I am facing an error :

```
  StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create: creating: create kic node: container name "minikube": log: 2022-08-03T16:19:15.374997860Z  + echo 'INFO: enabling containerd-fuse-overlayfs service'
2022-08-03T16:19:15.375006741Z  INFO: enabling containerd-fuse-overlayfs service
2022-08-03T16:19:15.375013843Z  + systemctl enable containerd-fuse-overlayfs
2022-08-03T16:19:15.398783149Z  Failed to enable unit, unit containerd-fuse-overlayfs.service does not exist.: container exited unexpectedly
```

So I search on the Internet and found this [Github repository](https://github.com/containerd/fuse-overlayfs-snapshotter) explaining how to install containerd-fuse-overlayfs.service that should resolve my problem.

I did not understand well the first option, so I have chosen to use the second option.
When I run the `containerd-rootless-setuptool.sh install` command (after installed them into `/usr/bin`). But I got an error too:

```
mount: /tmp/tmp.aecGG0JEwg/m: permission denied.
[rootlesskit:child ] error: command [mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/tmp/tmp.aecGG0JEwg/l,upperdir=/tmp/tmp.aecGG0JEwg/u,workdir=/tmp/tmp.aecGG0JEwg/w overlay /tmp/tmp.aecGG0JEwg/m] exited: exit status 32
[rootlesskit:parent] error: child exited: exit status 32
[WARNING] Overlayfs is not enabled, consider installing fuse-overlayfs snapshotter (`/usr/bin/containerd-rootless-setuptool.sh install-fuse-overlayfs`),  or see https://rootlesscontaine.rs/how-it-works/overlayfs/ to enable overlayfs.
```

So I decided to execute the next command anyway :

```
$ containerd-rootless-setuptool.sh install-fuse-overlayfs
containerd-fuse-overlayfs-grpc (https://github.com/containerd/fuse-overlayfs-snapshotter) needs to be present under $PATH
```

But I do not understand the error.

Anyone got an idea ? Thank you :)